# How to check and uncheck radio buttons with jquery and ajax?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am loading dynamically generated radio buttons using the ajax by select and while I am trying to uncheck the radio button, I don't know how it works. So can anyone help me in this?

Here is the Dynamically Generated HTML Code:

```html
enter code here
<table cellepadding='15' cellspacing='15' border='1' class='gridtable' align='center'>
<tr>
<td><strong>Service Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Daily</strong>
<td><strong>Weekly</strong></td>
<td><strong>BiMonthly</strong></td>
<td><strong>Monthly</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Inspection & Reporting</td>
<td>NA</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="radio" id="215" name="1" value="1/215" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>50</strong></td>
<td><input type="radio" id="200" name="1" value="2/200" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/>  <br> Rs. <strong>100</strong></td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" id="200" name="1" value="3/200" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>200</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>House keeping/Cleaning</td>
<td>NA</td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" id="322.5" name="2" value="7/322.5" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>75</strong></td>
<td><input type="radio" id="300" name="2" value="8/300" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/>  <br> Rs. <strong>150</strong></td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" id="300" name="2" value="9/300" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>300</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Utility Bill Payment</td>
<td>NA</td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" id="258" name="3" value="14/258" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>60</strong></td>
<td><input type="radio" id="240" name="3" value="15/240" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/>  <br> Rs. <strong>120</strong></td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" id="250" name="3" value="13/250" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>250</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Plumbing Inspection</td>
<td>NA</td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" id="129" name="4" value="19/129" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>30</strong></td>
<td><input type="radio" id="120" name="4" value="20/120" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/>  <br> Rs. <strong>60</strong></td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" id="240" name="4" value="21/240" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.id);" class="radio"/> <br> Rs. <strong>240</strong></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: you should get some result searching on google... Beware ID with dot is not valid

Comment: @A.Wolff: *"Beware ID with dot is not valid"* Yes, it is: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute The only restriction on IDs in HTML is that they can't contain spaces. CSS imposes further restrictions on *ID selectors* (like not allowing the ID in a selector to start with a digit), but that's not relevant if you're not using CSS ID selectors.

Comment: For example, [this script updating an element with a dot in its `id`](http://jsbin.com/zinevuyi/1) will work in any browser you want to try it in. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure this is valid in HTML5 but not in CSS. So, should we follow CSS specifications or HTML5 ones, better would be to fit to both, imho. That's the same thing for IDs starting with number, for me, still not valid. As usual, thx for your feedbacks, always appreciated ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff: I stick to the CSS rules for IDs, because I'm likely to want to use CSS selectors with them. But if you aren't, there's nothing invalid about using the full range of IDs available to you.

Answer (score 6):

Use these statements to check/uncheck radio buttons

```
    $('#radioID').attr('checked', true) - Check the radio button which has ID "radioID"
    $('#radioID').attr('checked', false) - This is to uncheck the radio button
```

Use this statement if you want to know whether the radio button is already checked

```
    var checked = $('#radioID').attr('checked');
```

Answer (score 4):

Here:

`$("input:checked").removeAttr("checked");`

http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-clear-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its worked for me.

```
document.getElementById('Usertype1').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you check and uncheck your radio button easily :

> ```
>     $('.btnRadio').bind('change', function() {
>         $(this).attr('checked','checked');
>     });
>     $('.btnRadio').bind('click', function() {
>         $(this).removeAttr('checked');
>     });
> ```

But this work only for Firefox. I use the double click to solve the problem :

> ```
>     $('.btnRadio').on('dblclick', function() {
>         $(this).removeAttr('checked');
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me - they did change the value of the radio set, but did NOT change the visual display, ie the attribute 'checked' was, indeed, removed, but the user still saw the radio button as selected.

This is what DID work for me:

```
$("#radioID").prop("checked", false);
```